# How to integrate new application with old existing application

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2

I have created one application in NetBeans. I think that application is enough(contains basic functionality). Now I would like to create another application that is question answer forum and want to integrate those forum with my old application.
 So how my old applications session values will accessed in my new application.
And how can i access my old applications other parameter(classes like for login, objects etc) will accessed from my new application.

Comment: Session values are a part of the web application, so it's a little wierd to think of sharing them.  Why do you want to separate the parts of the web app if they are so tightly related that they need to share the same sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a jar (assuming it is a standalone java application) file of your old application and include it in the build path of your new application. You will be able to access classes present in your old application

Comment: It is a web application.Can i access session parameters also from jar file

Comment: Ashish is suggesting that you separate the classes you want to share into a separate jar.  That jar can then deployed in the WEB-INF/lib of the web apps that want to use it.